# Formatação valor padra BRL em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estou com muita dificuldade em formatar um valor em BRL para um form. Gostaria que quando o usuario digitar o valor em BRL o ponto e virgula sejam posicionados automaticamente. Sem a necessidade do usuário digita-los. Por favor, alguem teria uma ideia ou um script pronto? muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei uma solução com Reg Exp. Você usa a expressão regular para localizar os valores números e substituí-los pela formatação em Real.

```
var test = 'R$ 1.700,90';



function getMoney( str )
{

        return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );

}

function formatReal( int )

{

        var tmp = int+'';

        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

        if( tmp.length > 6 )

                tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");


        return tmp;
}


var int = getMoney( test );

console.log( formatReal(1000) );

console.log( formatReal(12006) );

console.log( formatReal(1111) );

console.log( formatReal(120090) );

console.log( formatReal(int) );
```

Perceba que ele localiza o "valor" nesse trecho.

```
tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
```

e faz a substituição pelo valor em formato de "real brasileiro"

```
tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Somente uma pergunta. Estou utilizando um form pelo html. Como eu chama o script para validar?

Comment: poderia colocar o codigo html? ai eu digo como você poderia colocar.
Seria bem facil dizer